# send feedback form to email id with data feed in the form

Tags: android, email

I want send the data to the email address, when I fill the form and that data should be forward to the mail so no need to add any message in email, on click on submit button it should be send to the reciever,

here is my code,

```
 btnfeedbacksubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*
                Validation class will check the error and display the error on respective fields
                but it won't resist the form submission, so we need to check again before submit
                 */
                if ( checkValidation () )
                    submitForm();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(Feedback.this, "Form contains error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Email.setType("text/email");
                Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "abc@def.com" });
                Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
                Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Sending Feedback:"));
            }

        });
    }
```

this my form image

[image]

I want to send this detail via mail.

please help me in this problem,
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your form as a attachment. you can use below code to add attachment.

```
String message = etfeedbackname.getText().toString().trim()  + etfeedbackno.getText().toString().trim() + etfeedbackemail.getText().toString().trim() +etfeedbackmessage.getText().toString().trim();

Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Email.setType("text/email");
Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "abc@def.com" });
Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
Email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Sending Feedback:"));
```

You can specify your form path and send it as a attachment.

Comment: what is myimage.png here?

Comment: That is my path that i was sending image as a attachment, you can specify your path. and myImage.png is a file name you can specify there your file name. like form1.ext or anything that you want.

Comment: feedback.java, stored? it is an activity

Comment: see my edited post, i have given the screen shot i want to send that detail in email

Comment: Okay, can you just tell me the ID's name that you specified in your XML and java for Name. phone, email and message.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47482/discussion-between-innocentkiller-and-akky777)